# Google BigQuery data transfer - dataset copy

Tags: google-bigquery, dataset

I have a BigQuery dataset in my Google project project-everest:evr_dataset, I want to copy the its table data to my another BigQuery dataset which is sitting in an another project, project-alps:alp_dataset.

I attempted to use DTS - data transfer service to schedule the ingest job on a daily basis, but I don't see any option to choose the destination dataset from another project? Can anyone enlighten me how enable inter-project DTS?

Answer (score 1):

> You can use the below python function to create big query data transfer client and
> copy datsets from one project to another by specifying source and target project id's. You can also schedule the data transfer.
> In the method below it is set to 24 hours(daily).

```py
    def copy_dataset(override_values={}):
        # [START bigquerydatatransfer_copy_dataset]
        from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer

        transfer_client = bigquery_datatransfer.DataTransferServiceClient()

        destination_project_id = "my-destination-project"
        destination_dataset_id = "my_destination_dataset"
        source_project_id = "my-source-project"
        source_dataset_id = "my_source_dataset"
        # [END bigquerydatatransfer_copy_dataset]
        # To facilitate testing, we replace values with alternatives
        # provided by the testing harness.
        destination_project_id = override_values.get(
            "destination_project_id", destination_project_id
        )
        destination_dataset_id = override_values.get(
            "destination_dataset_id", destination_dataset_id
        )
        source_project_id = override_values.get("source_project_id", source_project_id)
        source_dataset_id = override_values.get("source_dataset_id", source_dataset_id)
        # [START bigquerydatatransfer_copy_dataset]
        transfer_config = bigquery_datatransfer.TransferConfig(
            destination_dataset_id=destination_dataset_id,
            display_name="Your Dataset Copy Name",
            data_source_id="cross_region_copy",
            params={
                "source_project_id": source_project_id,
                "source_dataset_id": source_dataset_id,
            },
            schedule="every 24 hours",
        )
        transfer_config = transfer_client.create_transfer_config(
            parent=transfer_client.common_project_path(destination_project_id),
            transfer_config=transfer_config,
        )
        print(f"Created transfer config: {transfer_config.name}")
        # [END bigquerydatatransfer_copy_dataset]
        return transfer_config
```